# How to sort queryset output in view django?

Tags: python, django, listview

I have these two models :

```
class Home(db_interface.Entity):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, help_text='Patient')
    sode = models.ForeignKey(Sode, help_text='sode')

class Sode(db_interface.Entity):
    start_date = models.DateField(validators=[validate_date_range], null=True, help_text="Start Date")
    path = models.ForeignKey('Path', null=True, blank=True)
                              help_text="Path")
```

and my view is inherited from a `ListView` of `Django` .To return a queryset I override `get_queryset()` method :

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        instance = self.get_instance()
        if instance:
            return Sode.objects.filter(patient=instance).select_related('path').prefetch_related(
            'home_set')
        return []
```

to list data in my template I use a for loop :

```
{% for h in sode.home_set.all %}
```

data is displayed in lists perfectly, but what I want to do now is to filter the list (not the standard filter approach) I mean the items in the list will be modified depending of the status of some items .

I tried to write a custom filter so that the every time my template is loaded I have data in the list are shown as I want. But I recognized that in my filter I used objects from database which must be in the view to separate  presentation code from data logic, so filtering models musn't be in a filter

I ended up by moving the logic I wrote in the custom filter to a function in my model's  `ListView`

```
    def sort_homes_per_sode(self,sode):
       homes = sode.get_queryset()
       #some logic here
       return list_homes_filtred_depending_on_the_type_of_some_homes_of_sode
```

I don't know if I'm in a good way, and still don't know if the function is usefull or not and how to show data in template and associate every filtered list of homes to the corresponding `sode`